# Binding Obj-C Categories in MonoTouch

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am trying to bind WEPopover over to MonoTouch using btouch. It uses a `UIBarButtonItem` category implementation to extend it's functionality to include presentation of the popover.

```
@interface UIBarButtonItem(WEPopover)

- (CGRect)frameInView:(UIView *)v;
- (UIView *)superview;

@end
```

How would I go about binding this into MonoTouch using a btouch interface definition?

Comment: Did anyone solved this?? How to bind categories in MonoTouch??

Answer (score 6):

My old answer missed the fact that categories were used. That was pointed out in the comments and the link to the Xamarin documentation did cover this. Quoting:

> In Objective-C it is possible to extend classes with new methods,
>   similar in spirit to C#'s extension methods.   When one of these
>   methods is present, you can use the `[Target]` attribute to flag the
>   first parameter of a method as being the receiver of the Objective-C
>   message.
>
> For example, in MonoTouch we bound the extension methods that are
>   defined on `NSString` when UIKit is imported as methods in the
>   `UIView`, like this:

```
[BaseType (typeof (UIResponder))]
interface UIView {
    [Bind ("drawAtPoint:withFont:")]
    SizeF DrawString ([Target] string str, PointF point, UIFont font);
}
```

From: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types#Binding_Class_Extensions

The above example is what MonoTouch uses to bind [`drawAtPoint:withFont:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawAtPoint:withFont:) which is part of the **NSString UIKit Additions**

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?? since I don't have the UIKit .h files  to see how was the objc code, maybe the binding code from the original question please :)

Comment: The header files comes with Xcode and without it you would not be able to use MonoTouch. The documentation for `drawAtPoint:withFont:` (link included in answer) tells you to look for `UIStringDrawing.h` then you can find it using: `find /Applications/Xcode.app/ -name UIStringDrawing.h` then open it using (something like) `open /Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIStringDrawing.h`. note: I won't copy/paste it since the file is copyrighted by Apple

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick (and untested) definition for the above:

```
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MonoTouch.Popover {
    [BaseType (typeof (UIBarButtonItem))]
    public interface WEPopover {
        [Export ("frameInView")]
        RectangleF FrameInView (UIView view);

        [Export ("superView")]
        UIView SuperView { get; }
    }
}
```

Then you use the **btouch** tool to compile the definition into a .dll usable from MonoTouch, e.g.

```
imac:tmp sebastienpouliot$ /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch we.cs 
imac:tmp sebastienpouliot$ ls -l we.dll
-rwxr-xr-x  1 sebastienpouliot  staff  5632 28 Aug 10:23 we.dll
```

I suggest you to read the existing documentation on how to bind existing ObjectiveC libraries. The document is available from: http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types

Comment: The problem is that those two members are actually *part* of UIBarButtonItem since obj-C category members are incorporated into the underlying type. So I don't think standard binding will work, at least it's not documented that I could see.

Comment: As stated, this wont work at all.  What you need to do is hand bind it and add extension methods to UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this yet?

Comment: Did anyone solved this?? How to bind categories in MonoTouch?? Any example on how to manually bind it?